# Python Flask : see declaration of 'ssize_t'

Tags: python

I am trying to install `pyreadr` package in VS code flask framework. But it is throwing me below error:

[image]

I have installed VS 2015 Build tools for this. I appreciate if anyone can help be to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know `pyreadr` is compatible with python 64 bit version only.